# How to run a function every time a UIViewController is loaded

Tags: swift, viewdidload

I have this function :

```
func setMoneyValues() {
        balanceLabel.text = User.current.roundBalance()
        oweLabel.text = User.current.roundOwed()
        userLabel.text = User.current.roundUser()
    }
```

that i execute in viewdidload. However, it is only called once, and if I go to another tab (managed by a tab bar controller), change the values, and come back to this page, the values are not updated, because the function is not called again. Anything I can do to make it be called everytime the tab is re-opened?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you want it in `viewDidAppear`, just be advised this is called when a dialog is over the controller and disappears, and also when the user backgrounds and comes back in the app, but given the nature of the code you posted, that's probably where you want it.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    setMoneyValues()
}
```

Also if you want it to update *before* the view appears, you can change to `viewWillAppear` it has the same signature otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You should get better results by moving it into viewDidAppear().

The viewDidLoad() function only gets called when the View is loaded into memory, which in a tab bar should happen only one time, IIRC.

The viewDidAppear() function will get called every time the view appears on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do what you want to do, rather than reloading the data every time the view appears, is to reload the data when the data is changed.

So the initial setup in view did load is okay, but what you could also do is in your User object set up an NSNotification that fires whenever the User data changes. You can then subscribe to this notification in the `viewDidLoad` method after setting the initial values, and in the notification handler, you can just set the values to the the new state.

A little cleaner than reloading in `viewDid/WillAppear` which can get called multiple times and just cause pointless polling and updating of unchanged information.